# How to recover a corrupt G.726 audio file?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, unix, file-corruption

I have an old audio file in g726 format, which I last opened three computers ago. It appears to be corrupt -- `ffmpeg` rejects it with `Invalid data found when processing input`...

It is not all zeros, so I'm hopeful there was only some "rot"...

How would I go about recovering (parts of) the recording? Can I somehow force `ffplay` or whatever other tool to keep looking for valid data even if the beginning is corrupted?

*More information*: the audio is part of a two-file recording created by an old Panasonic "web-cam", which writes the two streams (video and audio) into two separate files, named `audio-G726-32-1` and `video-MP4V-ES-2`.

`mplayer` and `ffplay` would both play the *video* stream, but not the audio. `vlc` would not play either.

Using `wavplay` on the audio stream, I get:

```
Playing WAV file audio-G726-32-1 :
Bad format: Cannot find RIFF file marker:
Reading WAV header from audio-G726-32-1
```

Audacity complains -- at startup -- that it cannot recognize the format, and offers me to try importing it as "raw data". Doing that I get nothing but noise -- and there is not anywhere, where I can tell it, this is a file in G726-format...

Comment: Have you tried alternative players?

Comment: Everything seems to be using ffmpeg's libraries underneath :-/

Comment: Mplayer sox/audacity and VLC dont use ffmpeg and often work where it doesnt. (All 3 are different libraries) At minimum they could help work out if the file is corrupt or just incompatible.

Comment: Ok, vlc seems to be trying harder, but, I suspect, treats my recording as an MP3 -- which it certainly is not. How would I tell it, that the file is _certainly_ in G726 format?